# Calling a Stored Procedure in MongoDB via C++

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11, stored-procedures

How can we call a stored procedure in MongoDB via c++? There are no proper documentation on that available.

Comment: IIRC, MongoDB doesn't have anything called stored procedure

Comment: @Danh : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

Comment: It's a stored JavaScript

Comment: Okay so how should i call a stored JavaScript in  MongoDB via c++ program.?

Comment: Question about tutorial is off topic

Comment: @danh : i didn't get you ? Is there a way to call a stored JS in mongoDB via c++ ?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't support stored procedures.  See JIRA ticket [SERVER-20510](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20510) about this topic.